# Extract large (100Gb) zip on ESXI host

Tags: vmware-esxi, zip

I have uploaded a vmdk file to my esxi 6.7 host and when i try to unzip it from cli with

```
unzip largefile.zip
```

i get this error

```
Archive: largefile.zip
unzip: short read
```

Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. Why would you try to unzip a vmdk file?

Comment: You can't unzip a vmdk file anyway. It's not a zip file.

Comment: i zipped it to be able to upload it faster. It got 110Gb from 240Gb. The file is a zip that contains a vmdk file. The checksum is ok so the file is not corrupted for sure but even with that running gzip -t on the file gives me the following error "gzip: invalid magic".

Comment: Gzip and ZIP are two different archive formats. Therefore it is expected that gzip can not until your zip file. Another problem may be the ZIP file size. The original ZIP format is limited to may 4GB files (decompressed). For larger files the ZIP64 format is used. Make sure to use an ZIP64 capable tool for unzipping.

Answer (score 2):

You are unable to unzip this because the built-in unzip does not support large zipfiles (greater than 4GB).

You could fix this by uploading a version of unzip that supports zip64.  I solved this by copying over the `/usr/sbin/unzip` binary from a VCSA VM to the host.

Comment: 's answer worked for me, VMware ESXi 7.0, still can't unzip larger files. Copied over unzip `/usr/bin/unzip` from vCenter Server, worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

This may be a corrupt file!
Recently, I uploaded a 20GB zip on vSphere 6.5, it takes a lot. But I checked that was a corrupt file, this may be due to the headers problem.